# Span class name from field name in database

Tags: cakephp

Is there a way to generate span class based on filed name in database?
Let's say  I have something like this in my layout:

```
<?php echo $offer['Offer']['title']; ?>
```

and want it to look like this:

```
<span class="title"><?php echo $offer['Offer']['title']; ?></span>
```

I forget to say it's cakephp 2.0.

Answer (score 1):

What's the problem?.

```
    <span class="<?=$fieldName?>"><?php echo $offer['Offer'][$fieldName]?></span>
```

Comment: Doesn't work or I don't get it. I get

    Notice (8): Undefined variable: fieldName [APP/View/Offers/index.ctp, line 21]

Notice (8): Undefined index:  [APP/View/Offers/index.ctp, line 21]